# Implementing JScrollPane/JTextArea in SwingWorker

Tags: java, implementation, jtextarea, swingworker, jscrollbar

I am having some trouble with my JScrollPane/JTextArea when using a SwingWorker. Here is what I currently have:

```
JTextArea txtDirs;
Task task;

//EDT
public void createGUI(){
    txtDirs = new JTextArea();
    txtDirs.setBounds(10, 56, 414, 125);
    txtDirs.setEditable(false);
    contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(txtDirs));

    task = new Task();
    task.execute();
}

class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>{
    @Override
    public void doInBackground(){
        for(file : files){
            txtDirs.append(file.getAbsolutePath);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void done(){
        closeWindow();
    }
}
```

This isn't the exact code, but it should give you the gist of it. Anyway, the problem is that the JScrollPane doesn't appear at all, though the code in the doInBackground() method does run. I expect it has something to do with it being updated (`txtDirs.append(file.getAbsolutePath())`) in the background task. However, I'm not quite sure how to make it work in this case. The frame appears as expected, but it is entirely blank. Should there be a "process" method in the `Task` class? And is that where the "`txtDirs.append(file.getAbsolutePath())`" should be placed? I'm afraid I'm rather new to the use of SwingWorkers, so any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

After a little confusion I decided I'd simply post my full code. I know there are things wrong with it, and I probably misunderstood some of what was mentioned in the comments, so I'm hoping posting this will allow someone to point out any obvious mistakes I've made.

Full code:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BasicCopy extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextArea txtCopiedDirs;
    private JButton btnCancel;
    private JProgressBar progressBar;
    private JLabel lblCopying;
    private String mainDrive;
    private String backupDrive;
    private String username;
    private String backupDir;
    long totalSize = 0L;        //total size of directories/files
    long currentSize = 0L;      //current size of files counting up to ONE_PERCENT
    long currentPercent = 0L;   //current progress in %
    long ONE_PERCENT;       //totalSize / 100
    Task task;

    public BasicCopy() {
    }

    public BasicCopy(String inDrive, String outDrive, String username, long space){
        mainDrive = inDrive;
        backupDrive = outDrive;
        this.username = username;
        totalSize = space*1048576;
        ONE_PERCENT = totalSize/100;
        createGUI();
    }

    public void createGUI(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Backup Progress");
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        txtCopiedDirs = new JTextArea(10, 50);
        txtCopiedDirs.setEditable(false);
        contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(txtCopiedDirs));

        btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        btnCancel.setBounds(169, 227, 89, 23);
        btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                closeWindow();
            }
        });
        contentPane.add(btnCancel);

        progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        progressBar.setBounds(10, 192, 414, 24);
        progressBar.setValue(0);
        contentPane.add(progressBar);

        lblCopying = new JLabel("Now backing up your files....");
        lblCopying.setBounds(10, 11, 157, 34);
        contentPane.add(lblCopying);

        setVisible(true);
        task = new Task();
        task.execute();
    }


    /**
     * Swing Worker class
     */
    class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, String>{
        @Override
        public Void doInBackground(){
            setProgress(0);

            //Create Backup Directory
            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy_HMMSS");
            String timestamp = sdf.format(date);
            backupDir = backupDrive + ":\\" + "Backup_" + timestamp;
            File backupDirectory = new File(backupDir);
            backupDirectory.mkdir();

            //Copy Files
            //Main directories
            String pics = mainDrive + ":\\Users\\" + username + "\\Pictures\\";
            String docs = mainDrive + ":\\Users\\" + username + "\\Documents\\";
            String vids = mainDrive + ":\\Users\\" + username + "\\Videos\\";
            String musc = mainDrive + ":\\Users\\" + username + "\\Music\\";
            //Backup directories
            String bkPics = backupDir + "\\Pictures\\";
            String bkDocs = backupDir + "\\Documents\\";
            String bkVids = backupDir + "\\Documents\\";
            String bkMusc = backupDir + "\\Pictures\\";

            String[] directories = {pics, docs, vids, musc};
            String[] bkDirectories = {bkPics, bkDocs, bkVids, bkMusc};

            //Loop through directories and copy files
            for (int i = 0; i < directories.length; i++){
                File dir = new File(directories[i]);
                File dest = new File(bkDirectories[i]);
                for(File file: dir.listFiles()){
                    try{
                        if(file.isFile()){
                            FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(file, dest);
                            publish(file.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
                        } else if (file.isDirectory()){
                            FileUtils.copyDirectoryToDirectory(file, dest);
                            publish(file.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
                        }
                        if(getDirSize(file) >= ONE_PERCENT){
                            currentPercent = getDirSize(file)/ONE_PERCENT;
                            progressBar.setValue((int)currentPercent);
                            currentSize = 0;
                        } else {
                            currentSize = currentSize + getDirSize(file);
                            if(currentSize >= ONE_PERCENT){
                                currentPercent = currentSize/ONE_PERCENT;
                                currentPercent++;
                                progressBar.setValue((int)currentPercent);
                                currentSize = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void process(List<String> chunks){
            for(String path : chunks){
                txtCopiedDirs.append(path);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void done(){
            closeWindow();
        }
    }

    public static Long getDirSize(File file) {
        long size = 0L;

        if (file.isFile() && file != null){       
            size += file.isDirectory() ? getDirSize(file) : file.length();
        } else if (file.isDirectory()){
            for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
            size += f.isDirectory() ? getDirSize(f) : file.length();
        }
        }
        return size;
    }

    /* Close current window */
    public void closeWindow() {
        WindowEvent close = new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(close);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

**EDIT #2:**

I have made some changes to the createGUI() method to avoid contentPane from having a null layout:

```
public void createGUI(){
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Backup Progress");
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    txtCopiedDirs = new JTextArea(10, 50);
    txtCopiedDirs.setEditable(false);
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(txtCopiedDirs);
    contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    btnCancel.setBounds(169, 227, 89, 23);
    btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            closeWindow();
        }
    });
    contentPane.add(btnCancel);

    progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
    progressBar.setBounds(10, 192, 414, 24);
    progressBar.setValue(0);
    contentPane.add(progressBar);

    lblCopying = new JLabel("Now backing up your files....");
    lblCopying.setBounds(10, 11, 157, 34);
    contentPane.add(lblCopying);

    setVisible(true);
    task = new Task();
    task.execute();
}
```

Comment: Make your `SwingWorker<Void,String>`  call `publish(filesNameString)` and override `process` , in process append to `txtDirs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't use `setBounds`, instead use [`JTextArea(rows, cols)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#JTextArea%28int,%20int%29)
- Don't modify the any UI components from outside of the EDT, instead use `publish` and override `process`.  `process` is called within the content of the EDT

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Possible causes of your problem include...

- Adding other components to the frame while it's using a `BorderLayout`, without specifying a position constraint (other than `BorderLayout.CENTER`)
- Calling visible before the components are added it

**Updated**

The main problem is, the `contentPane` is using a `null` layout and the scroll panes default bounds are `0x0` position by `0x0` width and height.

Best choice is to not use WinodwBuilder and learn how to use [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

**Update with example**

This is an example using two layout managers, `BorderLayout` as the base layout and `GridBagLayout` to provide some additional support for the extra components.

Basic rule of thumb.  If it's a UI component, ESPECIALLY if it's on the screen (or you don't know it's on the screen or not), you must only ever update it from the context of the EDT.

This means calling `progressBar.setValue` from within the `doInBackground` is a violation of the single thread rule of Swing.  `SwingWorker` provides progress updates via it's `PropertyChange` support

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class BasicCopy extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextArea txtCopiedDirs;
    private JButton btnCancel;
    private JProgressBar progressBar;
    private JLabel lblCopying;
    private String mainDrive;
    private String backupDrive;
    private String username;
    private String backupDir;
    long totalSize = 0L;        //total size of directories/files
    long currentSize = 0L;      //current size of files counting up to ONE_PERCENT
    long currentPercent = 0L;   //current progress in %
    long ONE_PERCENT;       //totalSize / 100
    Task task;

    public BasicCopy() {
    }

    public BasicCopy(String inDrive, String outDrive, String username, long space) {
        mainDrive = inDrive;
        backupDrive = outDrive;
        this.username = username;
        totalSize = space * 1048576;
        ONE_PERCENT = totalSize / 100;
        createGUI();
    }

    public void createGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Backup Progress");
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        txtCopiedDirs = new JTextArea(10, 50);
        txtCopiedDirs.setEditable(false);
        contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(txtCopiedDirs));

        JPanel controls = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);

        lblCopying = new JLabel("Now backing up your files....");
        contentPane.add(lblCopying, gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;

        progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        progressBar.setValue(0);
        contentPane.add(progressBar, gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;

        btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                closeWindow();
            }
        });
        controls.add(btnCancel, gbc);
        contentPane.add(controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        task = new Task();
        task.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if ("progress".equalsIgnoreCase(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                    progressBar.setValue((int) evt.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        });
        task.execute();
    }

    /**
     * Swing Worker class
     */
    class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

        @Override
        public Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            setProgress(0);

            //Create Backup Directory
            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy_HMMSS");
            String timestamp = sdf.format(date);
            backupDir = backupDrive + ":\\" + "Backup_" + timestamp;
            File backupDirectory = new File(backupDir);
            backupDirectory.mkdir();

            //Copy Files
            //Main directories
            String pics = mainDrive + ":\\Users\\" + username + "\\Pictures\\";
            String docs = mainDrive + ":\\Users\\" + username + "\\Documents\\";
            String vids = mainDrive + ":\\Users\\" + username + "\\Videos\\";
            String musc = mainDrive + ":\\Users\\" + username + "\\Music\\";
            //Backup directories
            String bkPics = backupDir + "\\Pictures\\";
            String bkDocs = backupDir + "\\Documents\\";
            String bkVids = backupDir + "\\Documents\\";
            String bkMusc = backupDir + "\\Pictures\\";

            String[] directories = {pics, docs, vids, musc};
            String[] bkDirectories = {bkPics, bkDocs, bkVids, bkMusc};

            //Loop through directories and copy files
            for (int i = 0; i < directories.length; i++) {
                File dir = new File(directories[i]);
                File dest = new File(bkDirectories[i]);
                for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
                    try{
                    if (file.isFile()) {
                        FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(file, dest);
                        publish(file.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
                    } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        FileUtils.copyDirectoryToDirectory(file, dest);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        publish(file.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
                    }
                    if (getDirSize(file) >= ONE_PERCENT) {
                        currentPercent = getDirSize(file) / ONE_PERCENT;
                        setProgress((int) currentPercent);
                        currentSize = 0;
                    } else {
                        currentSize = currentSize + getDirSize(file);
                        if (currentSize >= ONE_PERCENT) {
                            currentPercent = currentSize / ONE_PERCENT;
                            currentPercent++;
                            setProgress((int) currentPercent);
                            currentSize = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    } catch (IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void process(List<String> chunks) {
            for (String path : chunks) {
                txtCopiedDirs.append(path);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void done() {
            closeWindow();
        }
    }

    public static Long getDirSize(File file) {
        long size = 0L;

        if (file.isFile() && file != null) {
            size += file.isDirectory() ? getDirSize(file) : file.length();
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
                size += f.isDirectory() ? getDirSize(f) : file.length();
            }
        }
        return size;
    }

    /* Close current window */
    public void closeWindow() {
        WindowEvent close = new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(close);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think we discussed this once before. Maybe it wasn't you, but anyway, the "setBounds" was auto-generated, I will be going back and changing it once I get the code working. Will look at the link soon

Comment: That could mean that your frame is using a null layout, which would explain why you're not seeing anything

Comment: The frame works fine and components appear when I don't use the JScrollPane. The text appended just fine, but was cut off at the edges. This is the reason I was attempting to use a JScrollPane to display the text, so that the user can see all of it (by scrolling) if desired

Comment: As I suspected. The `contentPane` is using a `null` layout, but the position and size of the scroll pane is undefined (or 0). Best choice here is not to rely on WindowBuilder and learn how to use layout managers

Comment: Once again, I am not relying on WindowBuilder at all. I haven't used it since I first set up the basic layout of the window. I only used it to position the text area, progress bar, and button. Since then (a couple of days ago), I have only been editing the code itself. As for the contentPane/scroll pane, how is it supposed to be created? I knew I did a lot of things wrong, which is why I'm here.

Comment: BUT...the `contentPane` is using a `null` layout manager, meaning that unless you supply position and size information for your components, they will not show up.

Comment: I think I understand now what you mean. I'm adding an update to the createGUI() method to see if I'm on the right track.

Comment: Okay, please see Edit #2. Am I at least on the right track here? I do realize I still have to set the boundaries for the JScrollPane.

Comment: I've added an example using layout managers, I've not run it, as I'm on my Mac and the file references weren't going to work, but that's the basic idea

Comment: Understood. I was just working on it and after setting the bounds for the scrollPane (crudely), it does work now. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I'll post an update a little later, but right now I must ask--you mentioned updating the progress bar in doInBackground() is not a good idea. I have set up the propertyChangeListener so that it is updated using that. However, should the txtCopiedDirs.append() not be used in doInBackground?

Comment: No. You should not update ANY UI component outside of the EDT full stop

Comment: Just what I thought. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Even though I ended up using different code, I'm still going to accept this answer. There's a lot of good information here that helps significantly. Much obliged to everyone who responded, there were a lot of excellent and helpful replies!

Comment: Glad to see we got you to (I hope) a workable solution

Comment: Haha you did indeed. At the very least you opened my eyes to some of my stupid mistakes XD

Answer (score 1):

Try this, i don't know if `append` it's thread-safe, try calling in publish where you know that is called in `EDT`.

```
class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, String>{
    @Override
    public void doInBackground(){
        for(file : files){
            publish(file.getAbsolutePath); //or you can store them in an array and call it later
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void process(List<String> chunks){
           for(String filePath : chunks){
             txtDirs.append(filePath);
           }
    }

    @Override
    public void done(){
        closeWindow();
    }
}
```

If this doesn't help consider posting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Curious though, what about the JScrollPane? Should I leave that part the way it is?

Comment: @derstrom8 Try this first, updating components in another thread that is not `EDT` may cause problems, calling publish you know that will call process and process is executed in `EDT`. I couldn't find in java7 docs if `append` it's thread safe

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood this post. I should probably just add in my real code. I was just hesitant since it's somewhat long. I will add it in an edit to my original post.