# JProgresbar doesn't work with Files.copy

Tags: java, file, copy, jtextarea, jprogressbar

I am writing a program that creates a folder for each file in a specific folder. After that the file is copied in the, just created, folder. Everything works, except the JProgressbar I want to add to the program. I also added a Jtextarea but after a file is copied i want to change the progress bar, and add some text to the JTextarea. while the program runs nothing appears but when the whole task is completed all of the text I want in the JTextArea is shown and the progress bar is 100%. I don't know what i did wrong.

Comment: Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: Then have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835638/issues-with-swingworker-and-jprogressbar/24835935#24835935) and [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199091/progress-bar-java/15199220#15199220) and [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778551/implementing-jscrollpane-jtextarea-in-swingworker/20778585#20778585) as a starting point

Comment: oke tnx I will try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the examples that [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) gave me. I figured out how it worked. You need to update your progresbar in the Swingworker and all the Methodes you want to call, you need to call them in the SwingworkerMethod.